# Bootstrap switch change event not firing when state is changed from 'false' to 'true' dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-switch

I am using [Bootstrap Switch](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/) in my project to show a warning flag. Each time I try to set value of switch from false to true dynamically it is not going in `.bootstrapSwitch().on` method. It is working fine on changing switch state from false to true dynamically. Fiddle below-

http://jsfiddle.net/aanurn0j/

Comment: Click 'Off', it alerts false. Now click 'On', its not alerting

Comment: $('#bootstrapswitch').bootstrapSwitch('state', false, false);
$('#bootstrapswitch').bootstrapSwitch('state', true, true);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set third parameter to false and it works.

```
$('#toggleSwitchOn').click(function () {
    $('#bootstrapswitch').bootstrapSwitch('state', true, false);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aanurn0j/4/)

Comment: I didn't understand logic behind this

Comment: The method state can receive an optional third parameter skip. if true, switchChange event is not executed. The default is false.

Comment: I need something else, 
$(this).bootstrapSwitch({
          onSwitchChange: function(e, state) {
            if(state == false){
              //do something
            }else{
              //do something
            }
          }
        });
Also, I need to make the switch to be ON!